# How can i programmaticly get the WKT from WKID?

Tags: well-known-text

Is there some way (in C#/silverlight) to get the WKT from some web service with just the WKID?

Answer (score 1):

WKT if well know geometry where as WKID is the id for a coordinate system.  I think you might have your terms mixed up.

That being said, this might help you for WKT read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text

Comment: I do admit my understanding of GIS, is a bit limited. But, I can go to this site "http://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/102686/" that lists the WKID as 102686 and get a WKT.